# When to raise TypeError exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

[According](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) to Python 3 documentation, `TypeError` is

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.
>
> This exception may be raised by user code to indicate that an attempted operation on an object is not supported, and is not meant to be. [...]

The documentation however does not seem to give any guidelines about when one should actually go ahead and raise this exception.  Two extreme approaches are consistent with this documentation:

1. never raise `TypeError` explicitely,
2. check the type of every argument of every function and of every method if only certain particular types are expected (like `float` or `str`) and raise `TypeError` if the argument type is not among the expected ones.

Are there any established guidelines or traditions about raising `TypeError`?

Comment: Option 2 sounds right to me.  See, for example, section "2) Comparing objects from different classes/types" from this lecture from one of my college professors: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading1.txt

Comment: Actually, that snippet talks about returning "NotImplemented" instead of raising TypeError, which I guess is actually best practice for the comparison operators.

But doing ctrl+F on https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading2.txt will find some examples of explicitly raising TypeError.